# Cast hibernate Query result to Object of type class instead of list array

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there any way to Cast hibernate Query result to Object instead of list array.

```
Query q1 = session.createQuery("from userTable where id ='1234'");

List userList = q1.list(); >> cast to object of UserBean class type ??

UserBean user = (UserBean)userList.get(0); 

System.out.println(user.getName);
System.out.println(user.getAge);
.....
System.out.println(user.getPhone);
```

UserBean class is mapped with a table name userTable and i wish to get the column value of one `id` which is primary key of the table.

Please see at line 2, `List userList = q1.list()` ?? can we cast/convert to object of type class anyhow.

Comment: Try `UserBean user = (UserBean) q1.uniqueResult();`

Comment: @Reimeus Many thanks. it works. Please put this comment in answer so i would be able to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UserBean user = (UserBean) q1.uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use this?

```
UserBean user = (UserBean) q1.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: but i am getting a compiler error, `The method getSingleResult() is undefined for the type Query`, any suggestion ?

Comment: hello priyank, may u please clarify bit more about the method ?

Comment: @user1010399 : Its a method of Query Interface. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult%28%29 for more info. You shouldn't be getting compilation error.